# Powershell Get difference in values between dates

Tags: powershell

I'm trying chart some data from a csv. The csv is structured like date,state,temp.  What I'm trying to do is get the difference in the temp between the day prior and today.  So the dataset in the original csv might look like this:

```
20200323,AK,34
20200322,AK,35
20200321,AK,42
```

Once I import the csv I'm creating a customobject to add an object for the temp difference. But I am unsure of how I would get the temp difference between days.

```
$tempdata = Import-Csv -Path 'tempdata.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'          = $_.date
        'state'         = $_.state
        'temp'      = $_.temp
        'difference'      = ?
    }
}
```

Ideally I want the data in $tempdata to look like below, but I just can't wrap my brain around to do it. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
20200323,AK,34,-1
20200322,AK,35,-7
20200321,AK,42,$null or 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  to clean this up with how i'd actually write it:

```
$tempdata = @"
date,state,temp
20200323,AK,34
20200322,AK,35
20200321,AK,42
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


$out = for ($i=0; $i -lt $tempdata.count; $i++) {
    $n = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'date'          = $tempdata[$i].date
        'state'         = $tempdata[$i].state
        'temp'          = $tempdata[$i].temp
        'difference'    = $null
    }
    if ($tempdata[$i+1]) {
        $n.difference = $tempdata[$i].temp - $tempdata[$i+1].temp
    } 

    $n
}

$out | ConvertTo-Csv

##or 

$out | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv

"date","state","temp","difference"
"20200323","AK","34","-1"
"20200322","AK","35","-7"
"20200321","AK","42",
```

if you loop through the data using for, you can use the index to target the next or previous item in the array using positive or negative numbers.  The if ($tempdata[$i+1) is a check to ensure there is a 'previous day' to do math against.  Also, the way this math is occurring implies that the source files are all ordered the same; newest->oldest.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.